# CSS Sprites - using just one piece of an image as a background for part of an element

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I use the [CSS Sprite Technique](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) with a background image that looks something like this:

[image]

The CSS code for the icons:

```
div.icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("/images/icons.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: auto;
}
div.icon:empty {
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
div.icon:not(:empty) {
    padding-left:20px;
}
div.icon.attenuation {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

My icons can be used like this:

```
<div class="icon warning"></div>
```

I want to put some text inside my icons like:

```
<div class="icon warning">There is a warning on this page</div>
```

But the problem is that the background image covers the entire text area:

[image]

The question is: how can I use only part of an image as a background image for part of my element?

Notes:

- setting `width` to `16px` for `div.icon` doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two ways:

1)Your markup must be like this:

```
<div class="icon warning"></div><div class="txt">There is a warning on this page</div>
.icon {width:10px(for ex.)}
```

2)You must change the image. Icons in the image must be below the another

Comment: That will put the text underneath the icon, I thought it had to be to the right of it.

Comment: you are mistaken. .icon and .txt are both should have display:inline-block and text will be on right side of the icon

Comment: If `.txt` has `display:inline-block` then yes.

Answer (score 7):

Remember, where ever possible, you shouldn't change your markup just to achieve a design. It is possible using your markup.

```
div.icon:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("/images/icons.png");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 16px;
}

div.icon:not(:empty):before {
    margin-right: 4px;
}

div.icon.attenuation {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, my previous answer was not well though out.

Edit:
If you have a 16px padding, you should set the width to 0, not 16px. And I've got troubles getting the `:not(:empty)` bit to work on all browsers; better get rid of it. So the CSS becomes:

```
.icon {
  ...
  width:0; height:16px; padding-left:16px;
}
.icon:empty {
  width:16px; padding-left:0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGYgF/1/)

Comment: there is a problem with this method. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGYgF/2/

Comment: I see. You can remove the `display:inline-block` from the CSS, which will solve that. But I saw another problem: as soon as you put more than one word in there, each of the words displays to a new line. So jumancy's answer is better, even if it's got more markup.

Answer (score -1):

set `width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999em;` and remove `padding`

Comment: Dude he wants the the text in there, not the other way around.